# How do i set a default default image (no_pic.gif) php?

Tags: php, mysql, default

i have a default image in my pictures within the project but cant seem to be able to get it to reflect when user hasn't uploaded an image. Help please. below is the profile view and also the upload script

Profile.php:

```
<head>
        <title>Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">View Your Current Profile</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Title:</td>
                <td><?php echo $jobseekertitle; ?></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><?php echo $jobseekerfirstname; ?></td>

            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><?php echo $jobseekerlastname; ?></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><?php echo $jobseekeraddress; ?></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Phone:</td>
                <td><?php echo $jobseekerphoneno; ?></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>D.O.B (mm/dd/yyyy):</td>
                <td><?php echo $jobseekerdob; ?></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Gender:</td>
                <td><?php echo $jobseekergender; ?></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Picture:</td>

                <td><?php echo "<img src='$location' width='100' height='100'>";?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br><a href='upload.php'> Image upload</a>

        <br><a href='resumecreator.php'> Resume information</a>

         <br><a href='jobpreference.php'> Job Preference</a>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
// form in which we can upload the image
session_start();

include("connect.php");

// session as on website.

$jobseekerid = $_SESSION['jobseekerid'];

if($_POST['submit'])
{
    //get file attributes
    $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];


    if ($name)
    {
       // start upload process
       $location ="pictures/$name";
       move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);
// updating table users (setting image locaion
       $query = mysql_query("UPDATE jobseekers SET imagelocation='$location' WHERE jobseekerid='$jobseekerid'");

       die("Your avatar has been uploaded! <a href='profile.php'>Go back to view</a>");


    }
    else

        die("Please Select a file!");

}

echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

echo "Upload Your image:

<form action='upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
File: <input type='file' name='myfile'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='upload!'
>
</form>

";

?>
```

Comment: When I need to display an image for something I check the database image column and if the length is less than a certain number my server code applies the place holder image else the image in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do it like this

```
<td><img src="<?= @$location ? $location : 'default/image.gif' ?>" width="100" height="100" /></td>
```

That way if `$location` does not exist, it suppresses the error and outputs the default replacement.

Comment: Hello , Just tried that but its still just displaying a broken image. The dfault picture is no_pic.gif. Any more ideas on how to solve this.                       <td><img src="<?= @$location ? $location : 'pictures/no_pic.gif' ?>" width="100" height="100" /></td>

Comment: ick? i guess this would less icky? `<?php echo (isset($location)) ? '$location' : 'default/image.gif' ?>` - I don't agree

Comment: <td><img alt=""  src="<?php echo (isset($location)) ? '$location' : 'pictures/no_pic.gif' ?>" width="100" height="100" /></td>     tried again @jondavidjohn any more ideas....:-)