# How to set a default image

Tags: php, mysql, image, null, default

ok so I have the sql and the output for if someone has an image, how would I re-write this to set a default image if the user hasn't uploaded a profile picture?

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT users.username, users.id, tbl_image.photo, tbl_image.userid FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_image ON users.id=tbl_image.userid WHERE users.username LIKE '%$search_term%' and users.business <> 'business'");

<img src="/image/'.$results_row['photo'].'" width="50px" height="40px">
```

Comment: so this is php or something?  you should set the appropriate tag.

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111682/how-do-i-set-a-default-default-image-no-pic-gif-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the image is NULL or "", you use your default:

```
$image = $results_row['photo'];
if (empty($image)) $image = "default.png";
<img src="/image/'.$image.'" width="50px" height="40px">
```

Comment: @Steven, I've updated the answer. Instead of using `!$image`, use `empty($image)` as that would test for both `null` and empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if it's null or not. If it is, use a default photo.

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT users.username, users.id, tbl_image.photo, tbl_image.userid FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_image ON users.id=tbl_image.userid WHERE users.username LIKE '%$search_term%' and users.business <> 'business'");

$photo = $results_row['photo'] : $results_row['photo'] ? 'default_photo.jpg'

<img src="/image/'.$photo.'" width="50px" height="40px">
```